# How to upload image as url, not file?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want to upload images not from files but from url's that are submitted by the user, via a put call with a payload like `{"image_url":"http://example.com/1.jpg"}`.

What is the recommended way of doing this with DRF?

(So far my only option is to reimplement everything manually within my model view set. Is ther any better solution?)

UPDATE:

my serializer was:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField() #...

class PersonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    image = serializers.ImageField(required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ('image',)
```

Comment: can you post your model and serializer?

Comment: sure, it is a good idea

Answer (score 0):

Does the image actually need to be downloaded to the server? Can you not just save the URL in a CharField and pass it over to the client side for their browser to download? `<img src="{{ your_model.image_url }}>"`. Doing it like this would save alot of storage space on the server and mitigate many security checks required by this process which include making sure the image is not too large! **A user could provide an image that is 100GB, which could crash the server.** By downloading the image from a web URL and serving it yourself, you are effectively hosting an image which is already being hosted elsewhere.

HOWEVER, If you do wish to download the image, use a python based HTTP request library to download the image. Then use an ImageField in your model to handle the storage and recall of the image. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#imagefield

If you wished to perform the storage manually, you could save the file in a folder on the server, then save a link to this file in a CharField. Though as far as I am aware, this is essentially what the ImageField would do though for you.

Comment: Good thinking. I did want to upload the images, since images come and go on the internet, external links are usually unreliable. 
On the crash part: the webserver should usually be set to not accept too large HTTP contents.  
If there was no URLField serialization, probably I went with CharField serialization and ImageField storage. (by the way, I've got a lucky break: the URLField+ImageField combo automatically handles not only URLs but byte strings too)

Answer (score 0):

Well, what I ended up doing is using `URLField` at serialization.

```
class Person(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField()  

class PersonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    image = serializers.URLField()  
    # with a custom field serializer it is possible 
    # to make this field behave both as URLField (handling links)
    # and as ImageField (handling files)
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ('image',)

    def save(self):
        # handles the upload if the image url is external.
```

Comment: It's better if you add that example to the answer :)